# Phpmailer working fine in localhost But not in server

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');
include("classes/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$body = "this is <strong>testing</strong> mail ". date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;


$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";               
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
$mail->Port       = 465;              
$mail->Username   = 'my@email.com';
$mail->Password   = '*******';

$mail->SetFrom('my@email.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo('my@email.com','First Last');
$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "to@email.com"; // add your address here 
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Gmail Test");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

I have script like this.Its working fine with localhost but when i moving to windows or linux servers it won't work.I want to work on both windows and linux servers.What should i do?

Error like this:
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: You are using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an old example. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and start with [a good example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps). There are also many duplicates of this question. There is no great mystery here: when it says the connection timed out, it's because the connetcion timed out. Maybe you should [read the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php mailer google smtp working on localhost not working on live site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144469/php-mailer-google-smtp-working-on-localhost-not-working-on-live-site)

Comment: The duplicate that I marked uses *exactly* the same code as you - where did you get it from so I can try to stop people using it in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this :

```
require_once ( 'class.phpmailer.php' ); // Add the path as appropriate
$Mail = new PHPMailer();
$Mail->IsSMTP(); // Use SMTP
$Mail->Host        = "smtp.gmail.com"; // Sets SMTP server
 $Mail->SMTPDebug   = 2; // 2 to enable SMTP debug information
$Mail->SMTPAuth    = TRUE; // enable SMTP authentication
$Mail->SMTPSecure  = "tls"; //Secure conection
$Mail->Port        = 587; // set the SMTP port
$Mail->Username    = 'MyGmail@gmail.com'; // SMTP account username
$Mail->Password    = 'MyGmailPassword'; // SMTP account password
$Mail->Priority    = 1; // Highest priority - Email priority (1 = High, 3 = Normal, 5 = low)
$Mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
$Mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
$Mail->Subject     = 'Test Email Using Gmail';
$Mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
$Mail->From        = 'MyGmail@gmail.com';
$Mail->FromName    = 'GMail Test';
$Mail->WordWrap    = 900; // RFC 2822 Compliant for Max 998 characters per  line

$Mail->AddAddress( $ToEmail ); // To:
$Mail->isHTML( TRUE );
$Mail->Body    = $MessageHTML;
$Mail->AltBody = $MessageTEXT;
$Mail->Send();
$Mail->SmtpClose();

 if ( $Mail->IsError() ) { 
  echo "ERROR<br /><br />";
 }
 else {
  echo "OK<br /><br />";
  }
```

Comment: While this is marginally better than the original code, it won't work with the latest PHPMailer. Please don't suggest obsolete code.

Comment: What did you figure out? can you share the fix?

Answer (score -3):

What version of PHPMailer you are using ? if you are using old version try with

```
$mail->Port = 587;
```

try to update PHPMailer version that will solve i hope !!!

Comment: The OP's settings will work, but your suggestion won't unless you also set `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`